# Ignore backslash when reading tsv file in python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large `sep="|"` tsv with an address field that has a bunch of values with the following

```
...xxx|yyy|Level 1 2 xxx Street\(MYCompany)|...
```

This ends up as:

```
line1)  ...xxx|yyy|Level 1 2 xxx Street\
line2)  (MYCompany)|...
```

Tried running the quote=2 to turn non numeric into strings in read_table with Pandas but it still treats the backslash as new line. What is an efficient way to ignore rows with values in a field that contain backslash escapes to new line, is there a way to ignore the new line for `\`?

Ideally it will prepare the data file so it can be read into a dataframe in pandas.

Update: showing 5 lines with breakage on 3rd line.

```
1788768|1831171|208434489|2014-08-14 13:40:02|108|c||Desktop|coupon|49  XXX  Ave|Australia|Victoria|3025|Melbourne
1788772|1831177|202234489|2014-08-14 13:41:37|108|c||iOS||u7  38-46 South Street|Australia|New South Wales|2116|Sydney
1788776|1831182|205234489|2014-08-14 13:42:41|108|c||Desktop||Level XXX Margaret Street\
(My Company)|Australia|New South Wales|2000|Sydney|Sydney
1788780|1831186|202634489|2014-08-14 13:43:46|108|c||Desktop||Po box ZZZ|Australia|New South Wales|2444|NSW Other|Port Macquarie
```

Comment: Could you provide 3-4 sample lines in your tsv and the code that you are running at the moment?

Comment: Sure, I added 4 sample lines showing what the tsv looks like and a line where backslash breaks the row and returns to new line for rest of the row.

Comment: Why would you add those newline characters there? Does not make any sense to me, just keep one newline character per actual tsv row and you can avoid this whole mess.

Comment: I'm not adding it in there, it is in the file I am reading in, I am trying to ignore it :)

Comment: It was a DB dump and tsv craziness is what i am dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with sep which is **NOT** in values and it seems that it read correct:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
49  XXX  Ave|Australia
u7  38-46 South Street|Australia
XXX Margaret Street\
New South Wales|Australia
Po box ZZZ|Australia"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="^", header=None)
print df
                                              0
0                        49  XXX  Ave|Australia
1              u7  38-46 South Street|Australia
2  XXX Margaret StreetNew South Wales|Australia
3                          Po box ZZZ|Australia
```

Then you can create new file with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `sep="|"`:

```
df.to_csv('myfile.csv', header=False, index=False)



print pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep="|", header=None)
                                    0          1
0                        49  XXX  Ave  Australia
1              u7  38-46 South Street  Australia
2  XXX Margaret StreetNew South Wales  Australia
3                          Po box ZZZ  Australia
```

Next solution with not createing new file, but write to variable `output` and then [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `io.StringIO`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
49  XXX  Ave|Australia
u7  38-46 South Street|Australia
XXX Margaret Street\
New South Wales|Australia
Po box ZZZ|Australia"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", header=None)
print df
                                              0
0                        49  XXX  Ave|Australia
1              u7  38-46 South Street|Australia
2  XXX Margaret StreetNew South Wales|Australia
3                          Po box ZZZ|Australia

output = df.to_csv(header=False, index=False)
print output
49  XXX  Ave|Australia
u7  38-46 South Street|Australia
XXX Margaret StreetNew South Wales|Australia
Po box ZZZ|Australia

print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u""+output), sep="|", header=None)
                                    0          1
0                        49  XXX  Ave  Australia
1              u7  38-46 South Street  Australia
2  XXX Margaret StreetNew South Wales  Australia
3                          Po box ZZZ  Australia
```

If I test it in your data, it seems that 1. and 2.rows have `14` fields, next two `15` fields.

So I remove last item from both rows (3. and 4.), maybe this is only typo (I hope it):

```
import pandas as pd

import io

temp=u"""1788768|1831171|208434489|2014-08-14 13:40:02|108|c||Desktop|coupon|49  XXX  Ave|Australia|Victoria|3025|Melbourne
1788772|1831177|202234489|2014-08-14 13:41:37|108|c||iOS||u7  38-46 South Street|Australia|New South Wales|2116|Sydney
1788776|1831182|205234489|2014-08-14 13:42:41|108|c||Desktop||Level XXX Margaret Street\
(My Company)|Australia|New South Wales|2000|Sydney
1788780|1831186|202634489|2014-08-14 13:43:46|108|c||Desktop||Po box ZZZ|Australia|New South Wales|2444|NSW Other"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", header=None)
print df
                                                   0
0  1788768|1831171|208434489|2014-08-14 13:40:02|...
1  1788772|1831177|202234489|2014-08-14 13:41:37|...
2  1788776|1831182|205234489|2014-08-14 13:42:41|...
3  1788780|1831186|202634489|2014-08-14 13:43:46|...

output = df.to_csv(header=False, index=False)
```

```
print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u""+output), sep="|", header=None)
        0        1          2                    3    4  5   6        7   \
0  1788768  1831171  208434489  2014-08-14 13:40:02  108  c NaN  Desktop   
1  1788772  1831177  202234489  2014-08-14 13:41:37  108  c NaN      iOS   
2  1788776  1831182  205234489  2014-08-14 13:42:41  108  c NaN  Desktop   
3  1788780  1831186  202634489  2014-08-14 13:43:46  108  c NaN  Desktop   

       8                                      9          10               11  \
0  coupon                           49  XXX  Ave  Australia         Victoria   
1     NaN                 u7  38-46 South Street  Australia  New South Wales   
2     NaN  Level XXX Margaret Street(My Company)  Australia  New South Wales   
3     NaN                             Po box ZZZ  Australia  New South Wales   

     12         13  
0  3025  Melbourne  
1  2116     Sydney  
2  2000     Sydney  
3  2444  NSW Other
```

But if data are correct, add parameter `names=range(15)` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u""+output), sep="|", names=range(15))
        0        1          2                    3    4  5   6        7   \
0  1788768  1831171  208434489  2014-08-14 13:40:02  108  c NaN  Desktop   
1  1788772  1831177  202234489  2014-08-14 13:41:37  108  c NaN      iOS   
2  1788776  1831182  205234489  2014-08-14 13:42:41  108  c NaN  Desktop   
3  1788780  1831186  202634489  2014-08-14 13:43:46  108  c NaN  Desktop   

       8                                      9          10               11  \
0  coupon                           49  XXX  Ave  Australia         Victoria   
1     NaN                 u7  38-46 South Street  Australia  New South Wales   
2     NaN  Level XXX Margaret Street(My Company)  Australia  New South Wales   
3     NaN                             Po box ZZZ  Australia  New South Wales   

     12         13              14  
0  3025  Melbourne             NaN  
1  2116     Sydney             NaN  
2  2000     Sydney          Sydney  
3  2444  NSW Other  Port Macquarie
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using regex:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
f = open('input.tsv')
fl = f.read()
f.close()

#Replace '\\n' with '\' using regex

fl = re.sub('\\\\\n','\\\\',s)
o = open('input_fix.tsv','w')
o.write(fl)
o.close()

cols = range(1,17)
#Prime the number of columns by specifying names for each column
#This takes care of the issue of variable number of columns
df = pd.read_csv(fl,sep='|',names=cols)
```

will produce the following result:

[image]